# MergeMap and ForkJoin return data

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make nested http calls using mergeMap and forkJoin.

I want to call an API -> make two more inner api calls. Send the response of first API and the inner APIs.

I have the below code

```
    testmethod(): Observable<Gen | Observable<[UserForm, OtherForm]>> {
        return this.http.get<Gen>("http://test/genData")
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                const genericData = data;
                return genericData;
            }),
            mergeMap(data => {
                const url1 = data.url1;
                const url2 = data.url2;
                const user = this.http.get<UserForm>(url1);
                const other = this.http.get<OtherForm>(url2);
                return [data, forkJoin<UserForm, OtherForm>([user, other])];
           })
        )
    }
```

`ts` file

```
    this.service.testmethod().subscribe(item => {
        console.log('test(): ', item);
    }
```

Output:

```
    test(): {...}
    test(): Observable
```

two test() are getting logged to console. I want to get data withing the subscribe method.

Am I doing it the correct way. Is there something I need to change while returning from the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a `mergeMap` you should always return an Observable, here you are return an Array.

You can modify your return statement as:

```
return forkJoin<Gen, UserForm, OtherForm>([of(data), user, other]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, its working. I will accept the answer once it allows me.